# How to add a common Test branch to git?

Tags: git

We have a repo with a remote Master branch. Devs will create a new local branch named for a ticket number to do some work inside of existing folders. When we’re finished, we simply push into Master. Mostly we’ve had just one person working on things, but we added a couple more people and now we want to set up a common Testing branch that will let us checkin code for peer review before pushing to Master. I’m not clear what we need to do to make this work in terms of changing our workflow. Do we start by cloning Master into Testing? Or just add another pull between Master and our local repo? Then going back, how do we manage peer reviewed testing and possible updates?

I should add that we have things set up so we have a repo in a root folder with hundreds of separate project’s beneath it in their own folders, rather than separate repos for each project.

**To add some clarifications** first off, we have a lot of security issues we need to deal with (HIPAA, PCI, etc) and so we have our own internally hosted git server. Each of our VMs and laptops connects to it over a VPN. We have local clone of the masters on that server.

Our process seems a little strange to me, but this is what it is:

When we get a ticket to work on, we do this:

- git switch or checkout <ticket#>
- git pull origin master -- to ensure everything is up-to-date
- do the work and test
- add + commit our changes to the branch

When we're done, we do this:

- get switch <ticket#> (if needed)
- git pull origin master -- just to be sure
- git status -- to check what has been modified
- git checkout master
- git pull
- git merge <ticket#>
- git push origin master

This is a process that has been in effect for a decade or so now, and I was told to follow it.

**HISTORICALLY SPEAKING** ... tickets at this place are almost always handled entirely by one person. They used to use a centralized SCM (TFS), so they'd checkout files they needed from the server, make changes, test them, then check them in. I think they set up this git process to retain the overall flavor of that process. (I know that's ill-advised, but again, this was done long before I came to work at this place.)

Mostly, code is considered *in production*. A ticket will be submitted and we'll do some work on it, test it, then push it back to master and then into production.

Sometimes we create new projects. In those cases, we add a new folder, add the code (usually by copying code from a similar project), get it working, then push it into master and then into Production.

**WHAT WE WANT** is to allow multiple developers to review and test changes made to a project for a ticket *before* pushing it into master and Production. Right now, we can't do that. Files are either *local* to a dev, or globally accessible in master. If it's in master, then it's in Production, and vice versa.

Comment: Cloning and branch is not the right wording.
There is a lot of tools to do the review via merge request or pull request. What are you using at git server ?

Comment: What's the point of creating a branch with a different name locally only to push it to the master on the remote? Your process doesn't sound sensible.

Comment: The test branch sounds like something that would branch off master, and any feature/bug-fix branches would first be merged to testing, with the assumption that testing may not work at any given point. Periodically, when testing is *confirmed* to work, you would merge it back to master. Nothing else is merged directly to master.

Comment: Take a look at the diagram at https://jeffkreeftmeijer.com/git-flow/, in which the `develop` branch can be thought of as your testing branch.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "When we’re finished, we simply push into Master." Typically the devs would branch off of the latest master, and then do a Pull/Merge request into master, and when they're done their branch would be *merged* into master instead of *pushed*. Is that what you meant, or are the local feature branches literally pointing to master so the local branch commits can be pushed directly into master? (Which would be similar to doing a merge into master with a fast forward, when possible.)

Comment: It looks like my terminology is wrong. Sorry. Feel free to explain it better.

Answer (score 2):

If you have one testing branch for multiple developers, everyone mixes their work together. How do you know what you're testing? If there's a problem, how do you know which of multiple untested changes caused it? You avoid this by testing one change at a time. But one testing branch causes a bottleneck.

You need to test branches individually and in parallel. A test branch per change. And you have them.

> Devs will create a new local branch named for a ticket number to do some work inside of existing folders.

That is a "feature branch". When a dev is ready for their work to be reviewed and tested they push their feature branch upstream. Then people review and test the feature branch. Once it passes it is merged into master. Then the feature branch is deleted. This is the [Feature Branch Workflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/feature-branch-workflow) used by most Git projects.

Your process is 80% there. Your ticket branches are feature branches. The only change is to push and review them *before* merging.

- git switch <ticket#>
- git pull origin master   -- update your branch
- git push                 -- push your branch for review
- review the branch, fix any issues
- git switch master
- git pull
- git merge <ticket#>
- git push
- git branch -d <ticket#>    -- delete the local branch
- git push origin :<ticket#> -- delete the remote branch

This is much easier when its combined with a Git service such as [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/) which will manage and standardize the review, testing, and merging. Gitlab can be used as a paid service, or self-hosted for free.

[There are more workflows to choose from which handle more situations](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows). For example, [Gitflow](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/comparing-workflows/gitflow-workflow) incorporates maintaining multiple releases. They all build on the Feature Branch Workflow. Make a branch per issue. Test it. Merge it. Delete it.

> I should add that we have things set up so we have a repo in a root folder with hundreds of separate project’s beneath it in their own folders, rather than separate repos for each project.

This will *greatly* complicate matters. It will make branching and merging complex. It bloats the repository size making cloning expensive. It makes it difficult to determine what commit or branch or tag is for what project. It makes merging more complex, a simple merge to update your branch may drag in hundreds of unrelated changes.

Each project should get its own repositories. If they are interdependent use a dependency manager appropriate for your language. There are [tools to split repositories while retaining history](https://coderwall.com/p/0c-ayq/howto-split-a-git-repository-into-two).

Comment: I agree, the current process is complicated and messy. But it's what's in place and nobody wants to risk changing it.

Comment: @David The current process is already risky and its about to get worse. Technical debt sucks and it only compounds itself. Trying to manage a separate testing branch in the way you describe is complicated enough. One testing branch for *hundreds* of projects will be unmanageable. A path forward is to pick one project, pluck it out of the mega-repo, and manage it sensibly. Once it's demonstrated to be working well you can start plucking more projects. Feature Branch Workflow, Gitflow, and one-repo per project are all standard practices now. Mega-repos are an artifact.

Comment: Yes, I realize that. It might come at some point down the road. In the mean time, we need to get something working today.

Comment: @David If you want "*to allow multiple developers to review and test changes made to a project for a ticket before pushing it into master and Production*", simplest thing is to drop the idea of a single testing branch and use the Feature Branch Workflow; you're already 80% there. I'll edit the answer with exact changes. Consider using self-hosted Gitlab, [it should be HIPPA compliant](https://about.gitlab.com/solutions/hipaa-compliance/). Your situation is very common. I do Git training and process consulting if your company is interested.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [Git Flow](https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/).
It's well-thought, well-known, well-documented.
A lot of people use it and you can easily find PROs/CONs of that approach.
By the way, Git Flow has a few versions. I think I've linked probably the most known version, but there are some 'updates' or 'extensions' that add more paths/concepts, and for example - add scripts to install into your git, so you have new commands like `git hotfix start / git hotfix end` that automatically do a LOT of branching/merging properly for you.

Comparing what you wrote to GitFlow, if I understand your process well, then:

- your 'master' is GF 'master'
- your 'testing' is GF 'develop'
- your 'ticket branches' are GF 'feature branches'

Notice that GF introduces 'release branches' that are staging area before merging specific, ready-to-go version of 'develop' intto 'master'. You may not really need to do this staging, but it's often good to have anyways to mark very clearly what goes to master.

Using GF, note that depending on how often you decide to do releases, 'feature branches' and 'release branches' allow you to do a review the changes at least twice. First time is when feature is ready and is selected to be merged into the develop. Instead of just merging it by themselves, author of that branch can give it to someone else for review and merging. Then it stabilizes while teammates are fixing up the develop version after you broke it with yout feature :) Then, after some time, when we say 'develop is ready to go', release process starts, and again it can be reviewed before being merged to master. Although at this point the release branch may contain multiple changes, so it may be easy, or hard, to track and review specific changes, depending on how often you do the releases.

Also, if you want to have a specific TESTING branch that, maybe, the testing team will take and thoroughly test.. you need a stable version. Depending on your development team's momentum, you may find that develop changes too often and testers have not enough time to fetch and fully retest a new version every day.. or twice a day.. Therefore it may actually be more reasonable to, for example, test the `release` versions before merging them to master. This complicates making bugfixes on the fly to assist critical showblockers for testing team, because they use 'release' and it is always a bit older than 'develop'. Making a patch on 'release' means that it needs also to be merged into back into 'develop'. IIRC, in Git-Flow terminology, it's something near `hotfix` keyword.

I've just noticed **Schwern** also mentioned GitFlow in their answer.

By all means DO consider what Schwern said in "This will greatly complicate matters" paragraph. Try to split the monster repo as soon as possible. Working on a 100+ project workspace is a nightmare for almost any IDE. Yes, splitting the repo means that changing something and rebuilding something may break something else that you don't see because it is not loaded in the workspace. That's why you have CI like Jenkins. That's why you have feature branches. That's why you try to NOT change past code unless necessary and/or unless covered by automated tests (consider Open/Close principle!!!).